# saving a image to a file with php and changing the image name

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to send the param **imgName** (together with the picture) to php in order to change the "image default name to imgName"

```
var imgName = "30";     

file_data = $('#pictureInput').prop('files')[0];  
             form_data = new FormData();                  
             form_data.append('file', file_data); 

              var newdata = {imgName: imgName, form_data: form_data};
              var json = JSON.stringify(newdata);                
        $.ajax({
                url: 'editImage.php', 
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: json,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
```

**php**
(i need help with my php)

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'pictures/' . $imgName . '.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:-

```
$imgName = $_POST['imgName'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'pictures/' . $imgName . '.png');
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: imgName

Answer (score 0):

```
$imgName = tempnam('/pictures', '');
unlink($imgName);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $imgName);
```

I think using tempnam() is good for you. You do not need to worry about randomness.

Answer (score 0):

change your js code as

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#pictureInput');
if (imagefile.files && imagefile.files[0]) {
    formData.append("file", imagefile.files[0]);
}
```

and in ajax

```
data: formData,
```

Comment: how am i supposed to use the parameter **imgName**?